# Spark streaming with Kafka - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm currently stuck in an annoying situation. I'm trying to implement Kafka offset handling logic using Spark Streaming together with Kafka and MongoDB. The offset persistence to/from MongoDB does what it is supposed to do but when I try to create a direct stream using:

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> events = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
    jsc,
    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Assign(committedOffsetRanges.keySet(),kafkaParams, committedOffsetRanges)
);
```

I get the following exception (a lot of lines removed for brevity):

```
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Assign(ConsumerStrategy.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
```

I use the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>${spark-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>${spark-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

${spark-version} is set to "1.6.0-cdh5.12.1".
I've read that `org.apache.spark.internal.Logging` existed up to v 1.5.2 of Spark but unfortunately I'm not able to downgrade.
Hmmmmm... is there anybody who has found a solution to this or at least a workaround?

Comment: Can you upgrade your Spark version to use v2 ?

Comment: Upgrading to v 2.0.0-cloudera1 fixed the problem! Thanks for the suggestion.